# EF Code First Many to Many BaseEntity Inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I would like all my entities that are inheriting BaseEntity to have collection of one entity, this is my Sample

```
public abstract class BaseEntity : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }

    protected BaseEntity()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Notes = new List<Note>();
    }
}

public class Note
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public Note()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}

public class Student : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public School School { get; set; }
    public string SomeInfo { get; set; }
}

public class School : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to map it something like that, because by default table Notes has all ids of all tables (Student_Id, School_Id, etc)

[image: ManyToMany]

Any Ideas how to do this, or what to search?

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to have the `ManyToManyNotes` table/relation?

Comment: I woul like to have many to many table, but I don't know how to map it so all tables will use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an ObjectId to the notes table, to point to the related object (student, school, etc). And decorate your base class with the [ForeignKey("ObjectId")] attribute.

```
public abstract class BaseEntity : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ObjectId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }

    protected BaseEntity()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Notes = new List<Note>();
    }
}

public class Note
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ObjectId { get; set; } //student, school, etc
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public Note()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

This is one to many relationship, and does not require a mapping table, as you are using Guids as primary keys, you do not need to worry about object ids repeating in different tables.

Comment: nope doesnt work Consent_Notes_Source_Consent_Notes_Target: : The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.

Comment: It should work, check your code.  Does your table have only one Id field in that case?

Comment: It works, but you have any idea how to make such table without foreign key but with navigation property, because performance will be very slow

Comment: Relation with out foreign key

Comment: @AndrianDurlestean what do you mean without a foreign key, then how can you tell what that note belongs to? If you are talking about Database foreign keys, you cannot make the ObjectId a foreign key.But you should create an index on the ObjectId. You should not worry about the performance, because it will be lazy loaded. I was wondering what does the Name field in your Note table mean, are you considering using it as a foreign key? If so, when you add ObjectId you do not need it.

Comment: a lot of foreign keys in one table will be a performance problem, I found another solution, your idea is good, but for small DB with few tables.

Comment: @AndrianDurlestean Maybe there is a misunderstanding, you should have only one (ObjectId) field in the notes table, that is it. It will hold the value of the related object like school, student, etc.

Comment: I have only one, yes this is good, but in constrains I have all the foreign keys.